# Count how many times an action is executed and use that number

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies

There is a rails action I want to count each time it is executed for each user that goes on the site. After a certain number of times, then I can perform different actions.

My attempt has been with using cookies

```
cookies[:search_attempts] = 0 if cookies[:search_attempts].nil?

if contact_params.present? && cookies[:search_attempts].to_i < 2
  cookies[:search_attempts] = cookies[:search_attempts].to_i + 1
  # normal action
else
  # other action
end
```

The problem I see is when the user does not have cookies enabled. Also I plan to use this for when users have used the action a couple of times, so I would prompt the user to share.

I was also considering putting how many times a user has executed the action in to one of the user's attributes. This does not capture unregistered attempts.

Now that I think about it I could use the cookies temporarily until they register then save that to the db.

I would like to hear any alternatives to what I am thinking for solving this.

Answer (score 0):

Store the action execution count in a guest account by adding:

1. a boolean column to the user record to signify which users are
   guests—follow the directions in [Railscasts #393 Guest User
   Record](http://railscasts.com/episodes/393-guest-user-record) (quoted below); and
2. an integer column for the action
   execution count.

> [K]eep track of all the guests in the database […] add a
>   boolean guest column to the users table.